# php echo Catchable fatal error: Object of class ... could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, echo

I received the error while trying to display some variable like so:

```
echo "id is $url->model->id";
```

The problem seems to be that echo only likes simple variables to be displayed in this way (like $id or $obj->id).

```
class url {
    public function  __construct($url_path) {
        $this->model = new url_model($url_path);
    }
}

class url_model {
    public function  __construct($url_path) {
        $this->id = 1;
    }
}
```

and then

```
$url = new url();
echo "id is $url->model->id"; // does not work

$t = $url->model->id;
echo "id is $t";  //works

$t = $url->model;
echo "id is $t->id";  //works

echo "id is {$url->model->id}"; //works. This is the same syntax used to display array elements in php manual.

//php manual example for arrays
echo "this is {$baz['value']}";
```

I don't know why it works, I just guessed the syntax.

In php manual it doesn't say how to use `echo "..."` for objects. Also there is some strange behavior: echo on simple vars, works; echo on simple property of an object works; echo on simple property of an object that is inside another object does not work.

Is this `echo "id is {$url->model->id}";` the right way? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Welcome to the world of PHP, this is fairly daily routine. In my opinion the most solid way is `echo 'id is'.$url->model->id`. And you're on the safe side!

Comment: @Dan this is what I used to do and today I decided that maybe I should change... Well, maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"{$var}"` is the universal string variable interpolation syntax. There are some [syntax shortcuts known as simple syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for things like one-dimensional arrays:

```
echo "$arr[foo]";
```

This does not work for multi-dimensional arrays though, e.g. `"$arr[foo][bar]"`. It's simply a hardcoded special case. The same is true for objects. `"$obj->foo"` is a hardcoded special case that works, while more complex cases will have to be handled by the [complex `"{$obj->foo->bar}"` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. The manual should start with the universal syntax and then show the shortcuts... I will use '{$var}'.

Answer (score 1):

**update :**

maybe I am wrong , echoing `$url->model` or `$url->model->id` only  will try to convert it to string and  return it so  you can do it but  you must have `__toString` function in your model

i had do it an example to clear my point :

```
class url {
    public function  __construct($url_path) {
        $this->model = new url_model($url_path);
    }
}

class url_model {
    public function  __construct($url_path) {
        $this->id = 1;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->id ; 
    }
}

$url = new url("1");
echo "id is $url->model->id"; // it will  convert $url->model to "1" , so the string will be 1->id
echo "id is $url->model"; // this will  work now too 
$t = $url->model->id;
echo "id is $t";  //works
$t = $url->model;
echo "id is $t->id";  //works
echo "id is {$url->model->id}"; //works. This is the same syntax used to display array elements in php manual
```

but i am not sure what is `echo "this is {$baz['value']}";` for ?????

check [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) for more info about magic methods

but i'd rather stick with `{$url->model->id}` .

Comment: The `__toString()` just makes `$url->model` work, so the first output is `id is 1->id` :)

Comment: @tawfekov the $baz part was the example I've found in php manual for arrays. No example in the manual for objects. I put it there just to show how I've guessed the syntax for objects.

Comment: @tawfekov `echo "id is $url->model->id";` just displays `id is 1->id` as @Jack said. You are right about sticking to `{$url->model->id}`.